# Warn user before closing Vaadin window with unsaved changes

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm having a Pop-Up Window implemented as a child window of the main window.
I've an table with editable cells in it. (Basically it turns editable upon a double-click.)
Please suggest how I can make this window throw a warning to the user when an attempt is made to close the window having unsaved changes. I know partly that ConfirmDialog can be used to address this. However, identifying the unsaved data is the challenge I face.
I'm using Vaading 7.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a DAO Class to compare the persisted object with the in edit mode object and use a compare procedure. 
For example:

```
//table.getValue() returns you the selected object
public void compare(Object selectedObject) {

//getPersistedObjectById returns you the persisted (selected) object
Object persistedObject = getPersistedObjectById(table.getValue());

//compare all editable fields of the object
     if (persistedObject.name.equals(selectedObject.name)) {
        ....      
} else {
        ....
     }
  }
```